# How to pass parameters to the custom action?

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

I'm trying to create a custom action with "Value" attribute, I want to pass parameters to the C# code (the TARGETDIR and the version).

However, I get an error stating that DLLENtry and Value cannot coexist. But the custom action without dllentry is invalid.

This is the code:

```
 <CustomAction Id="SetMAWPrefferences"
                Value="InstallDir=[TARGETDIR];Version=2.0.0.1"
                Return="check"
                Execute="commit"
                BinaryKey="ImportExportBinary"                    
                />
```

And for it I get this error:

> Error  9   ICE68: Invalid custom action type for action 'SetMAWPrefferences'.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note, you're using `Value` attribute in the wrong way:

> ...this attribute must be used with the Property attribute to set the property...<sup>[Source](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html)</sup>

---

Based on the [Creating WiX Custom Actions in C# and Passing Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jschaffe/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters) article you should:

1. Create properties with desired values:

   ```xml
   <Property Id="InstallDir" Value="someDefaultValue" />
   <Property Id="Version" Value="2.0.0.1" />
   ```
2. Create custom action to set the `InstallDir` property:

   ```
   <CustomAction Id="SetDirProp" Property="InstallDir" Value="[TARGETDIR]" />
   ```
3. Create custom action:

   ```
   <CustomAction Id="SetMAWPrefferences" 
       Return="check" 
       Execute="commit" 
       BinaryKey="ImportExportBinary" 
       DllEntry="YourCustomAction" />
   ```
4. Schedule custom actions for execution during installation process:

   ```
   <InstallExecuteSequence>
       <Custom Action="SetDirProp" After="CostFinalize" />
       <Custom Action="SetMAWPreferences" ... />
       ...
   </InstallExecuteSequence>
   ```
5. Access those properties from your custom action as follows:

   ```cs
   [CustomAction]
   public static ActionResult YourCustomAction(Session session)
   {
       // session["InstallDir"]
       // session["Version"]
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi the values are not passing - I'm getting null.

Comment: Thank you, the values are passing! however, I get [TARGETDIR] as a string, and google isn't helpful - I need the path, not the name of the property.

Comment: @user1223457, I've updated the answer yet again, hope it helps.

Comment: No, I'm still getting just a string "TARGETDIR"

Comment: @user1223457, try changing `Value="[TARGETDIR]"` to `Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]"` in the `<CustomAction Id="SetDirProp"`.

Comment: Mo, not helping, still getting just a string. I do thank you for all your help! Perhaps there is another way?

Comment: `Execute="commit"`........... no. `Commit` CAs are executed after `InstallFinalize`, and only if rollback is enabled. If you're setting properties, they need to be done in `immediate` CAs, if you're changing the target system, they need to be done in `deferred` CAs. `Commit` CAs are for cleaning up temp files after successful install.

Comment: Sadly, they removed/disabled the MSDN blog. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 45):

There are two ways to pass parameters to the custom actions, one will work for the immediate execution CA and the other one will work for the deferred custom actions.

**Immediate CA (Can't be rolled back):**

In order to pass arguments to the immediate CA you can set a property with the required name and access it from your session.

In Wix:

```
<Property Id="MyProp" Value="MyValue" />
```

In CA:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult NameOfMyCA(Session session)
{
    string myArg = session["MyProp"];
}
```

**Deferred CA:**

In order to pass arguments to the deferred CA you need to use the [CustomActionData Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz(v=vs.80).aspx), this property is the only one you can access from a deferred CA.

In the case of WIX, the DTF includes a CustomActionData class which is a key/value dictionary, and you can access it using:

In Wix:

```
<CustomAction Id="MyCustomAction" .../>

<Property Id="MyCustomAction" Value="Arg1=value1;Arg2=value2;Arg3=value3;Arg4=[MyProperty]" />
```

In CA:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult NameOfMyCA(Session session)
{
    CustomActionData data = session.CustomActionData;

    //Access each argument like this:

    string arg1 = data["Arg1"];
    string arg2 = data["Arg2"];
    string arg3 = data["Arg3"];
}
```

**Immediate CA + CustomActionData:**

If you want to use the CustomActionData for your Immediate CA you can do something like this:

In Wix:

```
<Property Id="MyCustomAction" Value="Arg1=value1;Arg2=value2;Arg3=value3;Arg4=[MyProperty]" />
```

In CA:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult NameOfMyCA(Session session)
{
    CustomActionData data = new CustomActionData(session["MyCustomAction"]);

    //Access each argument like this:

    string arg1 = data["Arg1"];
    string arg2 = data["Arg2"];
    string arg3 = data["Arg3"];
    string arg4 = session.Format(data["Arg4"]);
}
```

In the case of Arg4 since it contains the value of a property you will need to access it like this:

```
string arg4 = session.Format(data["Arg4"]);
```

Unfortunately this will work in immediate CA only, this means that if you want to use the value of this property in a deferred CA you will need to have two custom actions:

- CA 1 to set the CustomActionData for the CA executed as immediate. (Remember to name the property with the same name defined for your CustomAction.
- CA 2 the CA with the specific logic that consumes CustomActionData.

I suggest you to use the CustomActionData for all the cases, this way is easier to convert you CA from Immediate to Deferred and the code is easier to read.

**References:**

[session.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371665(v=vs.85).aspx)
[CustomActionData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: I think this answer is missing the <custom action> that actually sets the property, e.g. `<CustomAction Id="SetDirProp" Property="InstallDir" Value="[TARGETDIR]" />`