# How to create a variable / property in Wix and pass to it the value of using C#?

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action, bootstrapper

How to create a variable / property in Wix and pass to it the value of using C#?

I am writing project installer and encountered a problem related to the transfer of value from C# ([CustomAction] Wix and Bootstrapper) to Wix Toolset 3.10. Both solutions do not work.

Solution 1:
**Using Wix Bootstrapper:**

```
Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["MyVariable"] = "test";
```

Solution 2:
**Using the Custom Actions:**
I create Bundle.wxs variable:

```
<Variable Name="MyVariable" Type="string" Value="" />
```

I set a property in the MSI Property, which should be the value of the variable "MyVariable":

```
<MsiProperty Name=" MYVARIABLE" Value="[MyVariable]" />
```

I create Product.wxs property:

```
<Property Id="MyVariable" Value="abcXYZ123" />
```

I create Product.wxs Custom Actions in which we set the property:

```
<CustomAction Id="MyVariable" Property="MyVariable" Value="[MyVariable]" />
```

I create a Custom Action in Product.wxs:

```
<CustomAction Id="Prefferences" 
    BinaryKey="MyCustomAction" 
    DllEntry="MySimpleAction"
    Execute="immediate" 
    Return="ignore" />
```

Performing during the installation process:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="Prefferences" After="InstallFiles">
    <![CDATA[Not Installed and Not Reinstall]]>
  </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I create in class Custom Action.cs access to these properties:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult MySimpleAction(Session session)
{
    session["MyVariable"] = "Test przesłania parametru!";
    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

Both solution does not convey the text of the C # code to Wix.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27449772/600559

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass parameters to the custom action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101579/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-custom-action)