# Passing an absolute path to a custom action in WiX

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I'm using WiX to create an installer for my application

I have this fragment which describes the destination install folder for my application:

```
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="Company" Name="myCompany">
          <Directory Id="App" Name="myProgram">
            <Directory Id="SQLGENERATORINSTALLFOLDER" Name="SqlLiteFolder" />
          </Directory>          
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
```

I also have a custom action which requires the `[App]` folder as an input parameter. If I pass `[App]` to the custom action I would expect the entire path of the folder, from C:\ all the way down to the inner folder

I would expect this:

> C:\ProgramData\myCompany\myProgram\

Instead, I get this:

> C:\Windows\Installer\MSI971.tmp-C:\ProgramData\myCompany\myProgram\

Looks like WiX is appending a temporary folder of some sort

**EDIT**

This is how I pass the `[App]` variable to the custom action:

```
  <CustomAction Id='GrantAccessToDatabase' BinaryKey='ActionLib' DllEntry='GrantAccess' Execute='deferred' Impersonate='no' />
  <Property Id="GrantAccessToDatabase" Value="DbFilePath=[App]" />
```

Please note that in order to pass a variable to a deferred custom action I need to use that syntax, it's explained here ->
[How to pass parameters to the custom action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101579/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-custom-action)

That's the C# part which receive the parameter:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult GrantAccess(Session session)
{
     var data = session.CustomActionData;
     var fullPath = data["DbFilePath"];
}
```

I would expect `fullPath` to be:

> C:\ProgramData\myCompany\myProgram\

Instead, I get:

> C:\Windows\Installer\MSI971.tmp-C:\ProgramData\myCompany\myProgram\

Comment: Please share the syntax of how you pass [App] to the custom action?

Comment: @AzazulHaq please look at the edit I just made

Comment: Could you please create a verbose MSI log? `msiexec -i yourinstaller.msi -l*v logname.txt`. Then look for log lines where property `App` gets assigned. I guess it's initially created with the value `C:\ProgramData\myCompany\myProgram\` but will be overwritten with the wrong value after that and before your custom action runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most cases, your installer is cached hence the temporary folder. You can instead concatenate the full path: `<...Value="DbFilePath=[CommonAppDataFolder]\myCompany\myProgram" />`.