# How to pass msiexec command line options to Wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a Wix Installer, `Product.msi`, which launches a setup.exe via Custom Action. When  I execute my Installer through Command Prompt, for example:
`msiexec /i Product.msi /q` 
 or 
`msiexec /r Product.msi /q` 
or 
`msiexec /x Product.msi`

I would like to pass `/i` `/r` `/q` `/x` options to setup.exe

Is it possible to achieve this through Wix Toolset?

Answer (score 1):

The flags you mention all set properties for the MSI, which you can then reference in your custom action, converting to whatever format you need for your setup.exe.

For instance:

`/i` corresponds to the value of `Installed` being false (if the product isn't already installed).

`/r` corresponds to a value of "Repair" on the `WixUIInstallMode` property.

`/x` corresponds to a value of "Remove" on the `WixUIInstallMode` property.

`/q` (and its modifiers like `/qn` and `/qb`) correspond to the `UILEVEL` property, which has the following values found from [this link](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Condition-for-Silent-Install-td706891.html).

```
UILevel:

INSTALLUILEVEL_NONE 2 Completely silent installation.
INSTALLUILEVEL_BASIC 3 Simple progress and error handling.
INSTALLUILEVEL_REDUCED 4 Authored UI, wizard dialogs suppressed.
INSTALLUILEVEL_FULL 5 Authored UI with wizards, progress, errors.
```

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27101890/7400944) if you're unfamiliar with passing values and referencing them in a custom action.

Comment: Thanks, @Kurt! Anyway, WixUIInstallMode property doesn't work at all, as explained in [this post](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/InstallMode-Conditions-DON-T-work-td707286.html) . Are there other solutions?