# Passing parameter to a WiX custom action not working

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, custom-action, wix3.10

I am trying to pass a parameter to a WiX custom action through wxs file. But I am getting the below exception.

```
Calling custom action CustomActionRemoveFolder!CustomActionRemoveFolder.CustomActions.CreateScheduleTaskForRunningWatchdog
Creating the Scheduled Task for running watch dog
Exception thrown by custom action:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.InstallerException: Cannot access session details from a non-immediate custom action
   at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Session.ValidateSessionAccess()
   at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Session.get_Item(String property)
   at CustomActionRemoveFolder.CustomActions.CreateScheduleTaskForRunningWatchdog(Session session)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object parameters, Object arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.CustomActionProxy.InvokeCustomAction(Int32 sessionHandle, String entryPoint, IntPtr remotingDelegatePtr)
CustomAction CA_scheduleTaskActionForWatchDog returned actual error code 1603 but will be translated to success due to continue marking
```

Below is how I am declaring and calling the parameter passing custom action in my wxs file.

```
 <Property Id="UserName" Value="someDefaultValue" />

<CustomAction Id="SetUserName" Property="UserName" Value="[UserName]"/>
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="SetUserName" After="InstallInitialize" />
 </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

And my custom action looks like this.

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult CreateScheduleTaskForRunningWatchdog(Session session)
{
  session.Log("The session value for username is " + session["UserName"]);
}
```

Then I am running the msi as

```
 msiexec /i <installer-name> UserName="myName" /l*v log.txt
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the exception says it: you cannot access properties like that from a **deferred** custom action (because those are long dead by the time when a deferred action script starts executing). Don't ask why. Windows Installer "was designed by most enlightened software astronauts and implemented by most lousy coders" (c) not me :)

What you could do:

Option 1: Make action `CreateScheduleTaskForRunningWatchdog` an immediate custom action. If not possible / does not make sense, go for option 2.

Option 2: Please refer to: [How to pass CustomActionData to a CustomAction using WiX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233267/how-to-pass-customactiondata-to-a-customaction-using-wix)

Comment: After changing the custom action CreateScheduleTaskForRunningWatchdog to immediate, that exception is gone. But now I am getting the default value for session["UserName"] inside the custom action CreateScheduleTaskForRunningWatchdog. Do you see any other issues here?

Comment: You probably need to set proper sequence.. first set the property, then get it. Make use of "After" attribute in the ExecuteSequence... Means, CreateScheduleTaskForRunningWatchdog  should go after SetUserName

Comment: <Custom Action="SetUserName" Before="CA_scheduleTaskActionForWatchDog" /> <Custom Action="CA_scheduleTaskActionForWatchDog" After="PublishProduct">NOT Installed</Custom>

Comment: Above is how I'm having it. Still its not having the passed in value. I  can see the passed value in the logs. After the "Doing action: SetUserName" log, the value I see is the default value :(

Comment: Wait a sec - isn't SetUserName assigning property to itself (isn't it a do-nothing action)?

Comment: That property won't be accessible inside the other custom action?

Comment: I was following the answer of this question btw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101579/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-custom-action

Comment: All properties should be accessible in all immediate custom actions.. you don't need to assign them to self specifically.

Comment: still getting the same thing even after removing the SetUserName custom action :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144216/discussion-between-nikolay-and-mayooran).